# Viewing java script package comments

Tags: javascript

I am writing a java script package.

I have an export class inside the package that I want the user to view my comment on this class when pointing the mouse on it in the declaration

How do i do it ?

Comment: It would depend on their IDE (and probably what extensions that had installed to do such things).

Answer (score 0):

Showing export class comments in Typescript

Write description on top of your export class

```
/**
 * @info
 * this is calculator class has for method add(), subtract(), divide(),multiply()
 */

export class CalculatorClass{}
```